# The drawable "ic_settings" in drawable has no declaration in the base drawable folder

Tags: android, wear-os

I added a vector asset to a wear os project using and cannot access it using:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.ic_settings);
```

It does not seem to be finding the asset. I have the Drawable directory and see the assets in it. I opened up the xml file and there is an error:

"The drawable 'ic_settings' in drawable has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier"

I have no idea what this means. I just added it using the New -> Vector Asset menu. Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Here is the line in the code:
[image]

Here is where it is in android studio:
[image]

When I look at the file:
[image]

Furthermore I have a roundbutton.xml in the drawable directory which is referred by R.drawable in another pice of code, and which there are no errors.

**UPDATE**

After doing all the checks (is the asset in the drawable directory), I closed and restarted Android Studio and it recognized them. Ye ol' reboot. Thanks to all for the responses. I am going to select the one which helped the most as the answer.

Comment: Put it into drawable folder.

Comment: It is in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your asset is specific to a certain configuration, so if the configuration doesn't match with device settings then the drawable can't be found by resource and will lead to a crash.

Some variants are:

```
- drawable (base, if not found in any folder)
- drawable-ldpi (low-resolution devices will look into it)
- drawable-mdpi (medium-resolution devices will look into it)
- drawable-v24 (devices with API level v24 or v24+ will look into it)
```

For more info, you can see: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

To Fix it:

1. Goto **Android** window and expand **app > res > drawable**, find the drawable, and right-click on it. From the menu goto **Refactor > Move File...**
   [image]
2. From the text edit box remove the substring after the word "*drawable*" (in the image you can see "*-xxxhdpi*" after the drawable word which we should remove) and press Refactor.
   [image]

Now, you're good to go.

Comment: It is already in the drawable directory. When I click on refactor this comes up: '.../src/main/res/drawable' so when I try and save it I get a message that it already exists.

Answer (score 7):

Saw the same message recently, but the cause was a hyphen in the file name.  I had copied the file `keyboard_alt-48px.xml` directly into the drawable directory:

[image]

Renaming to remove the hyphen resolved the problem.

For reference, trying to rename with the hyphen in the file name again was then highlighted as an invalid resource name:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I was trying to import SVG from Google Material Fonts and got stuck on this issue. After removing the hyphen (-) from the file name, it worked all right.

Comment: For me it was the drawable name "import" is not allowed. I named it "ic_import" now.

Answer (score 1):

Which helped me in a similar case with another file.
I redid a bunch of work to fix this error. Deleted the entire contents of the file in the IDE editor. Retyped and rechecked the contents of the entire project probably 10 times. Nothing helped. It seemed mystical.
The problem was solved like this:
I removed the ic_launcher_background.xml file. Not safe.
And created a new one. Then I typed the whole text again.
And everything became good.

Perhaps some hidden control character in the file interfered. I can't repeat the situation again.

Answer (score 1):

For me creating a new file in drawable directory (instead of copying it there) helped. I just copied and pasted **the content** of that file to the new which I created.